# architecture style for my app client-server, blackboard?

Tags: architecture, client-server, blackboard

I don't have much experience in software engineering. I need to decide witch architecture style suits my application. So any help is welcome.

Description of app:
    Our app communicates with Google maps API to get user location and shows near stores and Database witch stores descriptions about our products. User search specific item and gets information where is the nearest store. What is obvious is the client-server but i need some other ? Maybe blackboard or sth else ?

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is,

### User Story:

As a user I want to search for **specific item** and get the **nearest store** information.

### System Flow:

1. First locate the user location using Google Map API. So when user at
   your APP you need to check if this Device is connected to internet
   and GPS is open. If not, ask user to on it.
2. Get the nearest store based on the user location. If your database
   is in Web, you need to develop an API and send the User Location as
   Parameter [There might be other parameter based on your API set up
   and requirements].And, return the Store.
3. Get the Product details of the Nearest store and show to the
   user.You need another API here to get the product details. Develop
   Another API and pass the Store name / ID as Parameter at this API and
   return the Store product details.

So you need another 2 API (RESTful API might be easy and faster).
First API will rerun the Store and second API will return the Store
Product. From your App you need to call / consume the API.
Hope this will help, if there are any other difficulty to define the process and Flow, feel free to ask.